# Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1064

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a database from the E/R Diagram I just created using MySQL WorkBench, can someone please help?

Executing SQL script in server
`ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near`

```
CONSTRAINT `IDProveedor`
FOREIGN KEY (`IDproveedor`)
REFERENCES `Repu
```

`at line 11`

SQL Code:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `Repuestos`.`Articulo`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Repuestos`.`Articulo` (
      `IDArticulo` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `IDproveedor` INT NOT NULL,
      `Articulocol` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Valor_Unitario` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`IDArticulo`),
      INDEX `NitProveedor_idx` (`IDproveedor` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `IDProveedor`
        FOREIGN KEY (`IDproveedor`)
        REFERENCES `Repuestos`.`Proveedor` (`IDProveedor`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch.

Comment: Do you need that backtick at Repuestos.Proveedor(IDProveedor`) ?

Comment: Well, I actually don't know :/

Comment: I don't think VISIBLE (ie invisible indexes) are supported in mariadb. What version are you on?

Comment: MariaDB-10.1.36